# access sql appending column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that I need to Update by adding a new field.. I can alter the table and update each row . but is there a way  of appending the result of a query to the table? ( I know that the result will have the same number of rows)

EDIT: So let me make it clear
 I have

```
table1 | col1,col2
```

I generate another single column table

```
table2 | col1
```

I want

```
 table3 | table1.col1,table1.col2,table2.col1
```

By the way table1 & table2 have no common fields so I cant join them meaningfully.

Comment: Adding a new field and appending the result seems to be two questions. Please clarify your question, either you want to add new field to a table or you want appended results, and more over either append the result to a column of each row or "UNION ALL" kind of thing?

Comment: With no common field between the two tables you can't reliably match rows.  The database engine will have no way to know which row from table2 should be matched with which row in table1.

Comment: I think that changed the requirements of the question into something that's impossible. You can't join two tables without having something to join on.

Answer (score 1):

I think so. I haven't tested this, but what I can find it seems that you can use a [SubQuery](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html) to do something along the lines of
`UPDATE Table1 SET Column1 = Column1 & (SELECT Column2 FROM Table2 WHERE xxxx)`

Comment: While this is possible, it is probably not a good idea, I reckon @HansUp is right, and the OP need to think about this a bit more.

Comment: Initially the question didn't say there wasn't anything to join on. I assumed there was something and @dasman just wanted to concat a field with a sub query.